# Hash table based set

Tags: c++, set

## Purpose of the program

It is an attempt to implement Set ADT that can store case-insensitive (e.g. "SuNSET" == "sunset") strings using a hashtable in C++.

## Implementation

So far I have the interface of the Set ADT, its implementation and small testing file.

In order to implement set, I have used **djb2 algorithm** to hash strings and insert them on a bucket. To handle a collision, I used separate chaining technique with the help of **std::list**.  If a load factor of the hashtable is more than the maximum threshold, rehash is done.

Interface of Set ADT set.h:

```
#ifndef SET_H_
#define SET_H_

#include <ostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>

// Function to check string equality
bool equal(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2);

// Hash function
size_t hash(const std::string& s);


class set {

    std::list<std::string>* bucket_array; //buckets to store strings as a list

    size_t bucket_array_size;

    size_t set_size;

    const double max_load_factor = 3.0;

public:

    // Creates an empty set
    set() :
        bucket_array(new std::list<std::string>[4]), //hardcoded default constructor
        bucket_array_size(4),
        set_size(0)
    {

    }

    // Copy constructor
    set(const set& s);

    // Initializer list constructor
    set(std::initializer_list<std::string> ilist);

    // Copy assignment
    set& operator=(const set& s);

    // Returns true if val is not in the set and inserts it
    bool insert(std::string val);

    // Returns true if val is in the set
    bool contains(std::string val) const;

    // Removes val from the set and returns true if val is in the set
    bool remove(std::string val);

    // Remove everything from the set
    void clear();

    // Returns the total number of items in the set
    size_t size() const;

    // Returns whether or not the set is empty
    bool empty() const;

    // Returns the load factor of the hash table
    double loadfactor() const {
        return (double)set_size / (double)bucket_array_size;
    }

   // Print out the contents of the set -- showing the items
   // in each of the individual buckets
    void print(std::ostream& out) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bucket_array_size; ++i) {
            std::list<std::string> bucket = bucket_array[i];

            out << "bucket[" << i << "] = {";

                bool first = true;

                for (std::string val : bucket) {
                    if (first) {
                        out << val;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        out << ", " << val;
                    }
                }

            out << "}" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Destructor
    ~set();
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const set& s) {
    s.print(out);
    return out;
}

#endif /* SET_H_ */
```

Implementation of Set ADT set.cpp:

```
#include "set.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

bool equal(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    
    std::string lowercaseS1 = s1;
    std::string lowercaseS2 = s2;
    
    std::for_each(lowercaseS1.begin(), lowercaseS1.end(),
        [](char & c) {
            c = std::tolower(c);
        }
    );
    
    std::for_each(lowercaseS2.begin(), lowercaseS2.end(),
        [](char & c) {
            c = std::tolower(c);
        }
    );
    
    if(lowercaseS1 == lowercaseS2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    
}

size_t hash(const std::string& s) {
    
    size_t hashcode = 5381;
    for (auto c : s) {
        hashcode = (hashcode << 5) + hashcode + std::tolower(c);
    }
    return hashcode;
    
}

set::set(const set& s):
    bucket_array(new std::list<std::string>[s.bucket_array_size]),
    bucket_array_size(s.bucket_array_size),
    set_size(s.set_size)
{

    for(size_t i=0; i<s.bucket_array_size; i++) {
        bucket_array[i] = s.bucket_array[i];
    }
    
    
}

set::set(std::initializer_list<std::string> ilist):
    bucket_array(new std::list<std::string>[4]),
    bucket_array_size(4),
    set_size(0)
{    
    for(auto i: ilist) {
        insert(i);
    }
}

set& set::operator=(const set& s) {
    
    if(this != &s) {
        bucket_array_size = s.bucket_array_size;
        set_size = s.set_size;
        delete[] bucket_array;
        bucket_array = new std::list<std::string>[s.bucket_array_size];
        
        for(size_t i=0; i<s.bucket_array_size; i++) {
            bucket_array[i] = s.bucket_array[i];
        }
        
    }
    
    return *this;
}

bool set::insert(std::string val) {
    
    size_t index = hash(val) % bucket_array_size;
    
    if(!contains(val)) {
        
        if(loadfactor() > max_load_factor) { //rehash and rezise
            
            size_t new_bucket_array_size = bucket_array_size * 2;
            std::list<std::string>* new_bucket = new std::list<std::string>[new_bucket_array_size];
            set_size = 0;
            
            std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
            
            for (size_t i = 0; i < bucket_array_size; i++) {
                for(it = bucket_array[i].begin(); it != bucket_array[i].end(); it++) {
                    size_t new_index = hash(*it) % new_bucket_array_size;
                    new_bucket[new_index].push_back(*it); //rehashing old values and inserting into new bucket
                    set_size++;
                }
            }
            
            size_t val_new_index = hash(val) % new_bucket_array_size;
            new_bucket[val_new_index].push_back(val);
            set_size++;
            
            delete [] bucket_array;
            bucket_array = new_bucket;
            
            bucket_array_size = new_bucket_array_size;
            
        } else {
            bucket_array[index].push_back(val);
            set_size++;
        }
        
        return true;
    
    }
    
    return false;
    
}

bool set::contains(std::string val) const {
    
    size_t index = hash(val) % bucket_array_size;
    
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    for(it = bucket_array[index].begin(); it != bucket_array[index].end(); it++) {
        if(equal(*it, val)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
    
}

bool set::remove(std::string val) {
    
    size_t index = hash(val) % bucket_array_size;
    
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    for(it = bucket_array[index].begin(); it != bucket_array[index].end(); it++) {
        if(equal(*it, val)) {
            bucket_array[index].erase(it);
            set_size--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
    
}

void set::clear() {
    
    set_size = 0;
    delete [] bucket_array;
    bucket_array_size = 0;
    
}

size_t set::size() const {        
    return set_size;
}

bool set::empty() const {
    return (set_size == 0);
}

set::~set() {
    delete [] bucket_array;
}
```

Testing cases test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "set.h"

int main() {

    set example;

    example.insert("Kazuya");
    example.insert("Mizuhara");

    std::cout << example.contains("kazUYa") << "\n";
    std::cout << example.contains("mIzuHArA") << "\n;

    example.insert("Chizuru");
    std::cout << example.contains("Chiziri") << "\n";
    
    
    example.insert("Yukinoshita");
    example.insert("Yukino");
    example.insert("Mami");
    example.insert("Kanojo");
    example.insert("Sunset");
    

    example.insert("Horikita");
    example.insert("Alice");
    example.insert("Ellen");
    example.insert("Suzune");
    example.insert("Liza");

    std::cout << "Before remove:\n";
    std::cout << example << "\n";
    std::cout << example.size() << "\n";
    
    example.remove("Kanojo");
    
    std::cout << "After remove:\n";
    std::cout << example << "\n";
    std::cout << example.size() << "\n";

    auto example2 = example; // Copy constructor.

    std::cout << example << "\n";
    std::cout << example.size() << "\n";

    example2 = example; // Assignment.
    example = example;  // Self assignment.

    std::cout << example << "\n";
    std::cout << example.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << example2 << "\n";
    std::cout << example2.size() << "\n";

    example.clear();
    std::cout << example() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

## Problem with the program

When I output **example** set before calling **remove()** function, it shows:

```
Before remove:
bucket[0] = {Yukino, Horikita}
bucket[1] = {Yukinoshita, Mami, Ellen, Liza}
bucket[2] = {Kazuya, Mizuhara}
bucket[3] = {Chizuru, Kanojo, Sunset, Alice, Suzune}

13
```

Although it should not behave in such a way. I did debug at point before calling **remove()** function, and I discovered that **set_size** is 13, bucket_array_size is 4 which means that load factor already exceeded its maximum threshold (double(13/4) > double(3)). In that case, hash table should have got resized and values in there would have been distributed again via the hash function. However, as it's seen, it does not work that way.

I have been trying to figure it out but couldn't spot the place where the problem occurred.

Comment: `std::list<std::string>* bucket_array;` -- Use `std::vector<std::list<std::string>> bucket_array;` -- then the issue of trying to resize becomes trivial.

Comment: You check for rehash before you insert an item, not afterwards. So a size of 13 with four buckets is perfectly possible. The rehash willl happen when you insert the 14th item.

Comment: Koodos on not making the common mistake of declaring a Standard identifier like `set` and using `using namespace std;`. I salute you.

Comment: @user4581301 I would still have the home-made `set` in a namespace though, to avoid any clashes with `std::set`.

Comment: This is just for educational purposes right? otherwise you know you could just use an std::unordered_set<std::string> with a custom hash function for case insensitivity.

Comment: @jwezorek it is